# Why am I receiving no voltage to my load in this circuit?

Tags: relay

Please pardon the gap in my knowledge relating to proper electrical terms.

I have been converting my car to use dual electric fans and removing the stock mechanical fan.

The fans that I installed are listed as 25 amps each at startup, and 15amps each at speed.

I ran a 10 gauge wire to a relay ( Bueller BU5084W ) that is switched via radiator temperature, this then feeds power straight to the fans in parallel.

Whenever I first tested the circuit by bypassing the lead going to the radiator probe, the fans kicked on for about a second and then stopped.

I then tested the fans by jumping them straight to the battery and they work perfectly fine. I also tested the power at the pole input for the relay and it is 12v. I thought maybe I had burnt up the relay and since I have fifty of these laying around, i swapped it out with a new one, this time the fans don't even kick on, just the click of the relay switching. I then got paranoid and thought maybe i hooked the relay up wrong and probed the pole on the relay my fans were connected to, it showed 0v. I unhooked the fans from the pole and tested it again thinking maybe I wasn't getting a good contact with the fan wire in the way, it yielded 12v. This made me realize that every time I hook the fan wire up to the relay then it replicates this behavior.

At one point I thought that the relays were getting burnt up and i ran another relay in parallel with the first relay to shoulder more of the load from the initial 50amps at startup that the fans claim, this yields the same end result over both of the relays, 12v with no load attached, 0v with a load attached.

Because some people need to visualize a fused wire from a battery through a relay and to fans, here is a crude picture that i drew so the question doesn't get closed. [image]

Comment: Maybe these. https://www.qualitymobilevideo.com/bu5084w.html (that was a reply to a comment that was just now deleted.) Anyway, a circuit diagram of the setup would be good. Where exactly does the power to the relay coils come from, where does the power to the relay contacts come from, etc.

Comment: Too much hand waving.  It's not clear how exactly you have things hooked up.  Most likely that's where the mistake is.  Closing until a proper schematic is provided.

Comment: I can try to make something for you in paint if you would like?

Comment: @HatterisMad there is a schematic editor in the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/392523/edit) page. You can add your diagram there. Your paint diagram doesn't show the interesting connections on the relay. The product Dampmaskin linked is a SPDT, so you should show which pins are connected to your battery, your load, and whatever's driving the relay coil

Comment: Most of the established contributors on here can visualise the complete relay circuit correctly wired and fused and, can probably specify from memory, the sizes of cable for a given task. What you have been asked for is a diagram to identify where YOUR error may be...

Comment: That's just a scribble, not a schematic.  You are glossing over exactly where the error likely is.  Relays are more than just two-terminal blocks, and all the connections need to be labeled properly.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Considering I listed that the relay works with no load on it, and fails to work with load on them, you can deduce that the relay is hooked up correctly.

30: 10gauge wire from fuse
87: 10gauge wire to fans
87a: empty, also does not show 12v when 87 shows 0v
85: ground
86: jumped to battery for testing purposes

Comment: *deduce that the relay is hooked up correctly* Deduce is not what we do here.  When you say it works with no load, how do you define "works"? Maybe you see 12V on the pin going to the fans?   You might have a coil there rather than the contacts.  Please be specific and complete with your schematic.

Comment: @OlinLathrop That is fine, i was looking for theories as to why this might be working, grumpiness and snark is fine if you come in with decent ideas. I honestly don't care about the internet points, I have been on SO for too long to care about them.

Comment: @mike65535 I define works as I did in the original post and in the title of the question. The relays were operating properly when tested with a multimeter and no load, but dropping to 0v output when a load was added.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the fuse holder in my circuit is not conducting properly.

I jumped from before the fuse holder to behind the fuse holder ( with 86 on the relay still jumped to the battery ) and the fans kicked on properly.

Comment: I actually did consider suggesting that you checked your fuse(s) in one way or another, but as the first version of your question had no mention of fuses at all, I wasn't sure that you were even using them, and if so how and where. Which made the suggestion seem like a total stab in the dark. So I didn't. Here's the thing: In order to give advice about a circuit one needs to understand it, and in order to understand it, a complete and accurate description is strictly necessary. The sloppy description makes this a low quality question. But props for working out the problem on your own.

Comment: The ironic part being that I knew my circuit was correct, I tested it and proved it correct already. But instead of answering the question I was actually asking, of how can the circuit be correct but still not work, everyone zoned in on this must be a circuit problem, we can't trust the poster to be asking the correct question.

Comment: Dude, a correct question would have had a correct description of the problem. And a correct description of the problem would necessarily include a correct description of the circuit. Ever heard of the adage GIGO? The answer can never be better than the question, which is exactly why you didn't get any good answers.